# Using ProcessModelInfo with IIS 6.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-6

I want to use the information obtained by calling *System.Web.ProcessModelInfo.GetCurrentProcessInfo()*. But [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.processmodelinfo.aspx) says this method can only be used with IIS 5 or IIS 6 with IIS 5.0 isolation mode. I do not want to use IIS 5 isolation mode.
Is reading from Performance Counters the only way around?

Comment: Are you using IIS6 or 5? The docs seem to suggest it should work with IIS6.

Comment: I'm using IIS 6.It'll work with IIS 6 only if IIS is configured to run under IIS 5 isolation mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Process.GetProcessByName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9.aspx) to get the information on the [IIS worker process](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc735084(WS.10).aspx) that you're interested in.

Comment: Thank you JP.This definitely looks like a workable solution. I'll try it out and let u know.
Btw, do u think that calling this from a low privilege process like w3wp.exe will cause a problem , a security exception if you will..

Comment: If you're running with FullTrust, you should be fine.  But if not, here's a work around http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2005/12/14/502826.aspx

Comment: How do I can verify that it's running on FullTrust? I'm sorry I've a poor understanding of .Net Security model.

Comment: You should be running in FullTrust by default, but check out this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyts434y(vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The IIS architecture has been changed quite radically over the different versions. Personally I would not rely on anything that isn't part of the basic ISAPI filter and extensions APIs. Using the performance counters is likely to be more future proof.

For a definitive answer you should try to track down David Wang's current blog -- I don't have the rep to post links :/ It's been a while since I last read his blog, but if he's still active then you're going to get a much better answer from him (he's one of the main IIS developers at MS).

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you KayEss.I did checkout David Wang's blog and sure enough very insightful. But I couldn't find the answer to my problem though.